# how to remove this currency mark from js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to remove this "Rs." part from this js ? if i remove it html page not providing correct value its not working well i wannt stop replacing "Rs." on to my html page ?

```js
function print_today() {
  // ***********************************************
  // AUTHOR: WWW.CGISCRIPT.NET, LLC
  // URL: http://www.cgiscript.net
  // Use the script, just leave this message intact.
  // Download your FREE CGI/Perl Scripts today!
  // ( http://www.cgiscript.net/scripts.htm )
  // ***********************************************
  var now = new Date();
  var months = new Array('January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December');
  var date = ((now.getDate()<10) ? "0" : "")+ now.getDate();
  function fourdigits(number) {
    return (number < 1000) ? number + 1900 : number;
  }
  var today =  months[now.getMonth()] + " " + date + ", " + (fourdigits(now.getYear()));
  return today;
}

// from http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/number/round.html
function roundNumber(number,decimals) {
  var newString;// The new rounded number
  decimals = Number(decimals);
  if (decimals < 1) {
    newString = (Math.round(number)).toString();
  } else {
    var numString = number.toString();
    if (numString.lastIndexOf(".") == -1) {// If there is no decimal point
      numString += ".";// give it one at the end
    }
    var cutoff = numString.lastIndexOf(".") + decimals;// The point at which to truncate the number
    var d1 = Number(numString.substring(cutoff,cutoff+1));// The value of the last decimal place that we'll end up with
    var d2 = Number(numString.substring(cutoff+1,cutoff+2));// The next decimal, after the last one we want
    if (d2 >= 5) {// Do we need to round up at all? If not, the string will just be truncated
      if (d1 == 9 && cutoff > 0) {// If the last digit is 9, find a new cutoff point
        while (cutoff > 0 && (d1 == 9 || isNaN(d1))) {
          if (d1 != ".") {
            cutoff -= 1;
            d1 = Number(numString.substring(cutoff,cutoff+1));
          } else {
            cutoff -= 1;
          }
        }
      }
      d1 += 1;
    } 
    if (d1 == 10) {
      numString = numString.substring(0, numString.lastIndexOf("."));
      var roundedNum = Number(numString) + 1;
      newString = roundedNum.toString() + '.';
    } else {
      newString = numString.substring(0,cutoff) + d1.toString();
    }
  }
  if (newString.lastIndexOf(".") == -1) {// Do this again, to the new string
    newString += ".";
  }
  var decs = (newString.substring(newString.lastIndexOf(".")+1)).length;
  for(var i=0;i<decimals-decs;i++) newString += "0";
  //var newNumber = Number(newString);// make it a number if you like
  return newString; // Output the result to the form field (change for your purposes)
}

function update_total() {
  var total = 0;
  $('.price').each(function(i){
    price = $(this).html().replace("Rs.","");
    if (!isNaN(price)) total += Number(price);
  });

  total = roundNumber(total,2);

  $('#subtotal').html("Rs."+total);
  $('#total').html("Rs."+total);
  
  update_balance();
}

function update_balance() {

  var due = $("#total").html().replace("Rs.","") - $("#paid").val().replace("Rs.","");
  due = roundNumber(due,2);
  
  $('.due').html("Rs."+due);
}

function update_price() {
  var row = $(this).parents('.item-row');
  var price = row.find('.cost').val().replace("Rs.","") * row.find('.qty').val();
  price = roundNumber(price,2);
  isNaN(price) ? row.find('.price').html("N/A") : row.find('.price').html("Rs."+price);
  
  update_total();
}

function bind() {
  $(".cost").blur(update_price);
  $(".qty").blur(update_price);
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('input').click(function(){
    $(this).select();
  });

  $("#paid").blur(update_balance);
   
  $("#addrow").click(function(){
    $(".item-row:last").after('<tr class="item-row"><td class="item-name"><div class="delete-wpr"><textarea>Item Name</textarea><a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a></div></td><td class="description"><textarea>Description</textarea></td><td><textarea class="cost">Rs.0</textarea></td><td><textarea class="qty">0</textarea></td><td><span class="price">Rs.0</span></td></tr>');
    if ($(".delete").length > 0) $(".delete").show();
    bind();
  });
  
  bind();
  
  $(".delete").live('click',function(){
    $(this).parents('.item-row').remove();
    update_total();
    if ($(".delete").length < 2) $(".delete").hide();
  });
  
  $("#cancel-logo").click(function(){
    $("#logo").removeClass('edit');
  });
  $("#delete-logo").click(function(){
    $("#logo").remove();
  });
  $("#change-logo").click(function(){
    $("#logo").addClass('edit');
    $("#imageloc").val($("#image").attr('src'));
    $("#image").select();
  });
  $("#save-logo").click(function(){
    $("#image").attr('src',$("#imageloc").val());
    $("#logo").removeClass('edit');
  });
  
  $("#date").val(print_today());
  
});
```

```css
/*
  CSS-Tricks Example
  by Chris Coyier
  http://css-tricks.com
*/

* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body { font: 14px/1.4 Georgia, serif; }
#page-wrap { width: 800px; margin: 0 auto; }

textarea { border: 0; font: 14px Georgia, Serif; overflow: hidden; resize: none; }
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
table td, table th { border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; }

#no_bodear_tbl{
border: 0px solid black; padding: 6px;
}
#header { height: 15px; width: 100%; margin: 20px 0; background: #222; text-align: center; color: white; font: bold 15px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; text-decoration: uppercase; letter-spacing: 20px; padding: 8px 0px; }

#address { width: 250px; height: 150px; float: left; }
#customer { overflow: hidden; }

#logo { text-align: right; float: right; position: relative; margin-top: 25px; border: 1px solid #fff; max-width: 540px; max-height: 100px; overflow: hidden; }
#logo:hover, #logo.edit { border: 1px solid #000; margin-top: 0px; max-height: 125px; }
#logoctr { display: none; }
#logo:hover #logoctr, #logo.edit #logoctr { display: block; text-align: right; line-height: 25px; background: #eee; padding: 0 5px; }
#logohelp { text-align: left; display: none; font-style: italic; padding: 10px 5px;}
#logohelp input { margin-bottom: 5px; }
.edit #logohelp { display: block; }
.edit #save-logo, .edit #cancel-logo { display: inline; }
.edit #image, #save-logo, #cancel-logo, .edit #change-logo, .edit #delete-logo { display: none; }
#customer-title { font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; float: left; }

#meta { margin-top: 1px; width: 300px; float: right; }
#meta td { text-align: right;  }
#meta td.meta-head { text-align: left; background: #eee; }
#meta td textarea { width: 100%; height: 20px; text-align: right; }

#items { clear: both; width: 100%; margin: 30px 0 0 0; border: 1px solid black; }
#items th { background: #eee; }
#items textarea { width: 80px; height: 50px; }
#items tr.item-row td { border: 0; vertical-align: top; }
#items td.description { width: 300px; }
#items td.item-name { width: 175px; }
#items td.description textarea, #items td.item-name textarea { width: 100%; }
#items td.total-line { border-right: 0; text-align: right; }
#items td.total-value { border-left: 0; padding: 10px; }
#items td.total-value textarea { height: 20px; background: none; }
#items td.balance { background: #eee; }
#items td.blank { border: 0; }

#terms { text-align: center; margin: 20px 0 0 0; }
#terms h5 { text-transform: uppercase; font: 13px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; letter-spacing: 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid black; padding: 0 0 8px 0; margin: 0 0 8px 0; }
#terms textarea { width: 100%; text-align: center;}

textarea:hover, textarea:focus, #items td.total-value textarea:hover, #items td.total-value textarea:focus, .delete:hover { background-color:#EEFF88; }

.delete-wpr { position: relative; }
.delete { display: block; color: #000; text-decoration: none; position: absolute; background: #EEEEEE; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px 3px; border: 1px solid; top: -6px; left: -22px; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12px; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
 <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />

 <title>infintiaLK Billing</title>
 
 <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/style_bill.css' />
 <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/print_bill.css' media="print" />
 <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-1.3.2.min_bill.js'></script>
 <script type='text/javascript' src='js/example_bill.js'></script>

 <style type="text/css" media="print">
.dontprint
{ display: none; }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<?php
function wlcmMsg() {
    echo "Welcome ! ".$name=$_SESSION['adminlog']; 
}
session_start(); 
  if(!isset($_SESSION['adminlog'])){
   
  }

else if(isset($_SESSION['adminlog'])){

echo '<table align="right" border="0" class="dontprint">
<tr  width="50%"><td>Hi! '.$name=$_SESSION['adminlog']; echo '</td>
<td><form  align="right" action="menu.php"><input type="submit" value="Back" /></form></td>
<td><form  align="right" action="logout.php"><input type="submit" value="logout" id="search"/></form></td>
</tr></table>';


}


//connecting to the database 
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost'); 
define('DB_NAME', 'infinitiabill'); 
define('DB_USER','root'); 
define('DB_PASSWORD',''); 

$con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error()); 
$db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error()); 
//inserting Record to the database 


$result = mysql_query('SELECT InvoiceNo FROM billdata ORDER BY InvoiceNo DESC LIMIT 1;');
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
   $max_InvoiceNo = mysql_fetch_row($result);
  
   //echo $max_InvoiceNo[0]; //Here it is
}

 mysql_close($con); 

  ?>
 <script>
function myFunction() {
    window.print();
}
</script> 
  

 <div id="page-wrap">
 <form action="save_process.php" name="invicedata" method="post">
  <textarea id="header">INVOICE</textarea>
  
  <div id="identity">
  
            <textarea id="address">infintiaLK
No.210,Temple Road,
Ulukade Junction, Ganemulla,
Sri Lanka 11020.
(+94)76 75 57 909 / (+94)71 95 57 909
infinitialk@gmail.com
</textarea>

            <div id="logo">

              <div id="logoctr">
                <!--<a href="javascript:;" id="change-logo" title="Change logo">Change Logo</a>-->
                <a href="javascript:;" id="save-logo" title="Save changes">Save |</a>
                
                <!--<a href="javascript:;" id="delete-logo" title="Delete logo">Delete Logo</a>-->
                <a href="javascript:;" id="cancel-logo" title="Cancel changes">Cancel</a>
              </div>

              <div id="logohelp">
                <input id="imageloc" type="text" size="50" value="" /><br />
                (max width: 540px, max height: 100px)
              </div>
              <img id="image" src="images/logo1_bill.png" alt="logo" />
            </div>
  
  </div>
  
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
  
  <div id="customer">

            <textarea name="CmpnyName" id="customer-title">Company Name</textarea>

            <table id="meta">
                <tr name="invno">
                    <td class="meta-head">Invoice #</td>
                    <td ><?php echo $max_InvoiceNo[0]+1; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>

                    <td class="meta-head">Date</td>
                    <td><textarea name="issedate" id="date"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
     <tr>

                    <td class="meta-head">Created by</td>
                    <td><?php echo $name=$_SESSION['adminlog']; ?></div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="meta-head">Amount Due Rs.</td>
                    <td><textarea class="due" name="due" readonly>0.00</textarea></td>
                </tr>

            </table>
  
  </div>
  
  <table id="items">
  
    <tr>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Unit Cost</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
    
    <tr class="item-row">
        <td  class="item-name"><div class="delete-wpr"><textarea name="itemname">Web Updates</textarea><a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a></div></td>
        <td class="description"><textarea name="item_details">Monthly web updates for http://widgetcorp.com (Nov. 1 - Nov. 30, 2009)</textarea></td>
        <td><textarea class="cost">Rs.650.00</textarea></td>
        <td><textarea class="qty">1</textarea></td>
        <td>Rs.<span class="price">650.00</span></td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr  class="item-row">
        <td name="item_details" class="item-name"><div class="delete-wpr"><textarea  name="itemname">SSL Renewals</textarea><a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a></div></td>

        <td class="description"><textarea name="item_details">Yearly renewals of SSL certificates on main domain and several subdomains</textarea></td>
        <td><textarea class="cost">Rs.75.00</textarea></td>
        <td><textarea class="qty">3</textarea></td>
        <td>Rs.<span class="price">225.00</span></td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr id="hiderow">
      <td colspan="5"><a id="addrow" href="javascript:;" title="Add a row">Add a item</a></td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
        <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Subtotal Rs.</td>
        <td class="total-value" >875.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
        <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Total Rs.</td>
        <td class="total-value"><textarea id="total" name="total" readonly>875.00</textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
        <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Amount Paid Rs.</td>

        <td class="total-value"><textarea name="paid" id="paid">0.00</textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
        <td colspan="2" class="total-line balance">Balance Due Rs.</td>
        <td class="total-value balance"><div  class="due">0.00</div></td>
    </tr>
  
  </table>
  
  <div id="terms">
    <h5>Terms</h5>
   NET 30 Days. Finance Charge of 1.5% will be made on unpaid balances after 30 days.
    Make all checks payable to infinitiaLK.<br> THANK YOU FOR YOUR BUSINESS!
   
  </div>
  <div class="dontprint"><br>
  <center><table name="no_bodear_tbl">
  <tr><td>
  <form action="save_process.php"> 
  <input type="submit" value="Save" ></form></td>
  <td></td>
  <td><form action="http://pdfcrowd.com/url_to_pdf/">
  <input type="submit" value="Save to a PDF">
  </form></td>
  </tr></table></center>
  </div>
  
  <!--<button onclick="myFunction()">Print Bill</button>-->
 </form>
 

 <footer><br/>
<center> Copyright &copy; 2012 - 2015 infinitiaLK Inc.
</footer><br/>
</body> 

</html>
```

here m add html and css codes too herer

Comment: What's you snippet do? Can't see anything.

Comment: Can you put your html?

Comment: yah wait i will put my html code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited, @Sampath M Jay, I just change some code you just post on your snippet to make it work. Something need to know:

1. Did you see the the code snippet needs jQuery? I think that may be the reason that     your snippet is not working, anyway, I chose jQuery 1.11.0, which makes `.live` deprecated, so I change `$(".delete").live(...` to `$(".delete").on(...`, it just do the same thing.
2. The PHP part of your snippet is removed because stack snippet will not try to resolve it, so I believe whether to remove it or not is a minor issue.
3. Some of the html part also has the `Rs.` prefix, so remove them.
4. In js part, the `update_total`, `update_balance`, `update_price` and some part of the domready code which is

   ```
   $("#addrow").click(function() {
       $(".item-row:last").after('<tr class="item-row"><td class="item-name"><div...
       bind();
   ...})
   ```

   all of them have the relation with `Rs.`, so removed them.
5. Left is 'should-be-ok' version without the bothering `Rs.`, enjoy, and feel free to ask if there's any problem.

```js
function print_today() {
  // ***********************************************
  // AUTHOR: WWW.CGISCRIPT.NET, LLC
  // URL: http://www.cgiscript.net
  // Use the script, just leave this message intact.
  // Download your FREE CGI/Perl Scripts today!
  // ( http://www.cgiscript.net/scripts.htm )
  // ***********************************************
  var now = new Date();
  var months = new Array('January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December');
  var date = ((now.getDate()<10) ? "0" : "")+ now.getDate();
  function fourdigits(number) {
    return (number < 1000) ? number + 1900 : number;
  }
  var today =  months[now.getMonth()] + " " + date + ", " + (fourdigits(now.getYear()));
  return today;
}

// from http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/number/round.html
function roundNumber(number,decimals) {
  var newString;// The new rounded number
  decimals = Number(decimals);
  if (decimals < 1) {
    newString = (Math.round(number)).toString();
  } else {
    var numString = number.toString();
    if (numString.lastIndexOf(".") == -1) {// If there is no decimal point
      numString += ".";// give it one at the end
    }
    var cutoff = numString.lastIndexOf(".") + decimals;// The point at which to truncate the number
    var d1 = Number(numString.substring(cutoff,cutoff+1));// The value of the last decimal place that we'll end up with
    var d2 = Number(numString.substring(cutoff+1,cutoff+2));// The next decimal, after the last one we want
    if (d2 >= 5) {// Do we need to round up at all? If not, the string will just be truncated
      if (d1 == 9 && cutoff > 0) {// If the last digit is 9, find a new cutoff point
        while (cutoff > 0 && (d1 == 9 || isNaN(d1))) {
          if (d1 != ".") {
            cutoff -= 1;
            d1 = Number(numString.substring(cutoff,cutoff+1));
          } else {
            cutoff -= 1;
          }
        }
      }
      d1 += 1;
    } 
    if (d1 == 10) {
      numString = numString.substring(0, numString.lastIndexOf("."));
      var roundedNum = Number(numString) + 1;
      newString = roundedNum.toString() + '.';
    } else {
      newString = numString.substring(0,cutoff) + d1.toString();
    }
  }
  if (newString.lastIndexOf(".") == -1) {// Do this again, to the new string
    newString += ".";
  }
  var decs = (newString.substring(newString.lastIndexOf(".")+1)).length;
  for(var i=0;i<decimals-decs;i++) newString += "0";
  //var newNumber = Number(newString);// make it a number if you like
  return newString; // Output the result to the form field (change for your purposes)
}

function update_total() {
  var total = 0;
  $('.price').each(function(i){
    price = parseInt($(this).html());
    if (!isNaN(price)) total += Number(price);
  });

  total = roundNumber(total,2);

  $('#subtotal').html(total);
  $('#total').html(total);
  
  update_balance();
}

function update_balance() {

  var due = parseInt($("#total").html(), 10) - $("#paid").val();
  due = roundNumber(due,2);
  
  $('.due').html(due);
}

function update_price() {
  var row = $(this).parents('.item-row');
  var price = row.find('.cost').val() * row.find('.qty').val();
  price = roundNumber(price,2);
  isNaN(price) ? row.find('.price').html("N/A") : row.find('.price').html(price);
  
  update_total();
}

function bind() {
  $(".cost").blur(update_price);
  $(".qty").blur(update_price);
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('input').click(function(){
    $(this).select();
  });

  $("#paid").blur(update_balance);
   
  $("#addrow").click(function(){
    $(".item-row:last").after('<tr class="item-row"><td class="item-name"><div class="delete-wpr"><textarea>Item Name</textarea><a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a></div></td><td class="description"><textarea>Description</textarea></td><td><textarea class="cost">0</textarea></td><td><textarea class="qty">0</textarea></td><td><span class="price">0</span></td></tr>');
    if ($(".delete").length > 0) $(".delete").show();
    bind();
  });
  
  bind();
  
  $(".delete").on('click',function(){
    $(this).parents('.item-row').remove();
    update_total();
    if ($(".delete").length < 2) $(".delete").hide();
  });

  $("#cancel-logo").click(function(){
    $("#logo").removeClass('edit');
  });
  $("#delete-logo").click(function(){
    $("#logo").remove();
  });
  $("#change-logo").click(function(){
    $("#logo").addClass('edit');
    $("#imageloc").val($("#image").attr('src'));
    $("#image").select();
  });
  $("#save-logo").click(function(){
    $("#image").attr('src',$("#imageloc").val());
    $("#logo").removeClass('edit');
  });
  
  $("#date").val(print_today());
  
});
```

```css
/*
  CSS-Tricks Example
  by Chris Coyier
  http://css-tricks.com
*/

* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body { font: 14px/1.4 Georgia, serif; }
#page-wrap { width: 800px; margin: 0 auto; }

textarea { border: 0; font: 14px Georgia, Serif; overflow: hidden; resize: none; }
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
table td, table th { border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; }

#no_bodear_tbl{
border: 0px solid black; padding: 6px;
}
#header { height: 15px; width: 100%; margin: 20px 0; background: #222; text-align: center; color: white; font: bold 15px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; text-decoration: uppercase; letter-spacing: 20px; padding: 8px 0px; }

#address { width: 250px; height: 150px; float: left; }
#customer { overflow: hidden; }

#logo { text-align: right; float: right; position: relative; margin-top: 25px; border: 1px solid #fff; max-width: 540px; max-height: 100px; overflow: hidden; }
#logo:hover, #logo.edit { border: 1px solid #000; margin-top: 0px; max-height: 125px; }
#logoctr { display: none; }
#logo:hover #logoctr, #logo.edit #logoctr { display: block; text-align: right; line-height: 25px; background: #eee; padding: 0 5px; }
#logohelp { text-align: left; display: none; font-style: italic; padding: 10px 5px;}
#logohelp input { margin-bottom: 5px; }
.edit #logohelp { display: block; }
.edit #save-logo, .edit #cancel-logo { display: inline; }
.edit #image, #save-logo, #cancel-logo, .edit #change-logo, .edit #delete-logo { display: none; }
#customer-title { font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; float: left; }

#meta { margin-top: 1px; width: 300px; float: right; }
#meta td { text-align: right;  }
#meta td.meta-head { text-align: left; background: #eee; }
#meta td textarea { width: 100%; height: 20px; text-align: right; }

#items { clear: both; width: 100%; margin: 30px 0 0 0; border: 1px solid black; }
#items th { background: #eee; }
#items textarea { width: 80px; height: 50px; }
#items tr.item-row td { border: 0; vertical-align: top; }
#items td.description { width: 300px; }
#items td.item-name { width: 175px; }
#items td.description textarea, #items td.item-name textarea { width: 100%; }
#items td.total-line { border-right: 0; text-align: right; }
#items td.total-value { border-left: 0; padding: 10px; }
#items td.total-value textarea { height: 20px; background: none; }
#items td.balance { background: #eee; }
#items td.blank { border: 0; }

#terms { text-align: center; margin: 20px 0 0 0; }
#terms h5 { text-transform: uppercase; font: 13px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; letter-spacing: 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid black; padding: 0 0 8px 0; margin: 0 0 8px 0; }
#terms textarea { width: 100%; text-align: center;}

textarea:hover, textarea:focus, #items td.total-value textarea:hover, #items td.total-value textarea:focus, .delete:hover { background-color:#EEFF88; }

.delete-wpr { position: relative; }
.delete { display: block; color: #000; text-decoration: none; position: absolute; background: #EEEEEE; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px 3px; border: 1px solid; top: -6px; left: -22px; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />

  <title>infintiaLK Billing</title>
  
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/style_bill.css' />
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/print_bill.css' media="print" />
  <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-1.3.2.min_bill.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='js/example_bill.js'></script>

  <style type="text/css" media="print">
.dontprint
{ display: none; }
</style>
</head>

<body>

  <script>
function myFunction() {
    window.print();
}
</script> 
    

  <div id="page-wrap">
  <form action="save_process.php" name="invicedata" method="post">
    <textarea id="header">INVOICE</textarea>
    
    <div id="identity">
    
            <textarea id="address">infintiaLK
No.210,Temple Road,
Ulukade Junction, Ganemulla,
Sri Lanka 11020.
(+94)76 75 57 909 / (+94)71 95 57 909
infinitialk@gmail.com
</textarea>

            <div id="logo">

              <div id="logoctr">
                <!--<a href="javascript:;" id="change-logo" title="Change logo">Change Logo</a>-->
                <a href="javascript:;" id="save-logo" title="Save changes">Save |</a>
                
                <!--<a href="javascript:;" id="delete-logo" title="Delete logo">Delete Logo</a>-->
                <a href="javascript:;" id="cancel-logo" title="Cancel changes">Cancel</a>
              </div>

              <div id="logohelp">
                <input id="imageloc" type="text" size="50" value="" /><br />
                (max width: 540px, max height: 100px)
              </div>
              <img id="image" src="images/logo1_bill.png" alt="logo" />
            </div>
    
    </div>
    
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    
    <div id="customer">

            <textarea name="CmpnyName" id="customer-title">Company Name</textarea>

            <table id="meta">
                <tr name="invno">
                    <td class="meta-head">Invoice #</td>
                    <td ><?php echo $max_InvoiceNo[0]+1; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>

                    <td class="meta-head">Date</td>
                    <td><textarea name="issedate" id="date"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
         <tr>

                    <td class="meta-head">Created by</td>
                    <td><?php echo $name=$_SESSION['adminlog']; ?></div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="meta-head">Amount Due </td>
                    <td><textarea class="due" name="due" readonly>0.00</textarea></td>
                </tr>

            </table>
    
    </div>
    
    <table id="items">
    
      <tr>
          <th>Item</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>Unit Cost</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
          <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
      
      <tr class="item-row">
          <td  class="item-name"><div class="delete-wpr"><textarea name="itemname">Web Updates</textarea><a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a></div></td>
          <td class="description"><textarea name="item_details">Monthly web updates for http://widgetcorp.com (Nov. 1 - Nov. 30, 2009)</textarea></td>
          <td><textarea class="cost">650.00</textarea></td>
          <td><textarea class="qty">1</textarea></td>
          <td><span class="price">650.00</span></td>
      </tr>
      
      <tr  class="item-row">
          <td name="item_details" class="item-name"><div class="delete-wpr"><textarea  name="itemname">SSL Renewals</textarea><a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a></div></td>

          <td class="description"><textarea name="item_details">Yearly renewals of SSL certificates on main domain and several subdomains</textarea></td>
          <td><textarea class="cost">75.00</textarea></td>
          <td><textarea class="qty">3</textarea></td>
          <td><span class="price">225.00</span></td>
      </tr>
      
      <tr id="hiderow">
        <td colspan="5"><a id="addrow" href="javascript:;" title="Add a row">Add a item</a></td>
      </tr>
      
      <tr>
          <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
          <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Subtotal</td>
          <td class="total-value" >875.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>

          <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
          <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Total</td>
          <td class="total-value"><textarea id="total" name="total" readonly>875.00</textarea></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
          <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Amount Paid</td>

          <td class="total-value"><textarea name="paid" id="paid">0.00</textarea></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
          <td colspan="2" class="total-line balance">Balance Due</td>
          <td class="total-value balance"><div  class="due">0.00</div></td>
      </tr>
    
    </table>
    
    <div id="terms">
      <h5>Terms</h5>
     NET 30 Days. Finance Charge of 1.5% will be made on unpaid balances after 30 days.
      Make all checks payable to infinitiaLK.<br> THANK YOU FOR YOUR BUSINESS!
      
    </div>
    <div class="dontprint"><br>
    <center><table name="no_bodear_tbl">
    <tr><td>
    <form action="save_process.php"> 
    <input type="submit" value="Save" ></form></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><form action="http://pdfcrowd.com/url_to_pdf/">
    <input type="submit" value="Save to a PDF">
    </form></td>
    </tr></table></center>
    </div>
    
    <!--<button onclick="myFunction()">Print Bill</button>-->
  </form>
  

 <footer><br/>
<center> Copyright &copy; 2012 - 2015 infinitiaLK Inc.
</footer><br/>
</body> 

</html>
```

Comment: I believe the `Rs.` is added by `update_price`'s `sNaN(price) ? row.find('.price').html("N/A") : row.find('.price').html("Rs."+price);`, note that I also removed it.

Comment: can u check snippet i add my project there

Comment: your method is working but issue is with it not calculating each item price with the quantity

Comment: 'with it not calculating each item price with the quantity', I'm not sure I get it, would you explain it more detail?

Comment: yah its mean i upload my project to snippet did you check it ? 
there in my invoice for each item you can define cost and give quantity then it will calculate total of that specific item n show it in price column this invoice will calculate all prices column including each item and will show you total !! with your re correction that my replacing fault solved but now its not calculating each item price if i enter quantity it cant calculate price can you help me to fix it cz m not much familiar with js

Comment: I believe you see my edit, and find out that the edited ver. in my answer is now worked?

Comment: yah ur code working well but  still there got some issue i cant understand it :(

Comment: issue is now its not replacing Rs. but its not calculating total when  i add quantity for any item

Comment: If you use my code, but still not work, try open dev-tool in chrome (by press `F12` or `Ctrl+Shift+j`) and do some action, then see if the console is popping out any error, if there is some error, paste here and we can see how to solve that.

Comment: i checked console not sowing any issue if u can send me ur mail id i will send you my project zip file then you can see the error dreamzofsampath@gmail.com mine

Answer (score 2):

Try doing <kbd>**[`split`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)**</kbd> instead.

Ex:

```
function update_balance() {
    var total= parseInt($("#total").html().split("Rs.")[1]);
    var pval=parseInt($("#paid").val().split("Rs.")[1]);
    var due = total-pval;
    due = roundNumber(due,2);
    $('.due').html("Rs."+due);
}
```

Same goes with `update_price()`

Answer (score 0):

You should remove "Rs" string being added at locations mentioned below. Then you can remove all `replace("Rs.","")`

```
function update_total() {
   ...
   $('#subtotal').html("Rs."+total);
   $('#total').html("Rs."+total);
   ...
}

function update_balance() {
   ...
   $('.due').html("Rs."+due);
   ...
}

function update_price() {
   ...
   row.find('.price').html("Rs."+price);
   ...
}
```